# Close program window from terminal without killing process

Tags: bash

I'm using linux and have a program which I want to automatically open and close on startup (with my "autostart" script). how can I do it?

details: the program is `xfce4-taskmanager`, it opens with a little notification icon which I want in the taskbar, but I don't want the whole window open (this is why I want to open->close, so I get only the icon). I found no other way to get just the icon, but if there is it's also good. killing the process with `kill` or `killall` removes both the window and the icon.

Thanks ahead

Comment: Not a duplicate if I understoo correctly. I want to close the taskmanager GUI window and leave the taskbar icon

Comment: Hi Oded, please see the link I posted above. If it doesn't work, please leave a comment. (please @ping me in case)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks, it can do the trick (with `xdotool key alt+F4` instead of minimize). However I have to give it a delay so the task manager has enough time to load GUI. A more snappy/clean alternative will be better if exists

Comment: You are not using the script? It should work cleanly and without interference.  `xdotool key alt+F4` is not the solution in the mentioned dupe :)

Comment: bc I don't want the window minimized, both windowminimize and windowkill(which kills the process) don't work for me here

Comment: I am afraid you can only *hide (minimize)* or *unmap* a window of a GUI application. *closing* it will simply kill the process, unless the application is designed to run some background process without window.

Comment: @DavidFoerster done, thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### GUI applications have windows

What you want to achieve is only possible if an application is *designed* te have a background process running with no window.

#### Hiding the windows

Normally, a GUI application cannot run without its window, and killing the window *is* killing the application. What can be done to make the window *invisible* though, is:

- hiding the window by minimizing it
- hiding the window by unmapping it

Both can be done programmatically with the help of `xdotool`, but if your goal is to *destroy* the window without destroying the application, I am afraid there is no way.

Comment: Your answer lead me to the similar script I wrote, as I said before, what I'm using is `xdotools key alt+F4` to close the window, it leaves the icon in the tray as I want. Thanks